service dependancy graph( novatec-service-dependency-graph-panel)
is anyone help me to configure service dependancy graph( novatec-service-dependency-graph-panel) to me share documentation helpful suggestion as i am using loki-grafana promethous stack whcih is running on k8s as pod and deployed through helm and on my grafana dashboard service dependancy graph is already installed and i am using open source version of grafana(Grafana v10.3.3 (252761264e)) .
some proper guiadeness
